# PHPMailer HTML with a variable using BCC

Tags: php, html-email, phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer, I have set it all up and working everything is fine, however I have run into a problem.

I need for each recipient to receive the HTML slightly different which is a link within the HTML email. So the link would have to change for each recipient.

I could simply use a php loop that sends it one by one to each recipient, however this will take a lot of processing and could time out the request I do not want this to happen.

Is there away I can use shortcodes using curly brackets as you would on most wysiwyg editors `{email}` so then I do `$mail->send()` once as oppose to loop through all of the recipients and do `$mail->send()` for each one, which I am trying to avoid.

If you need any more information I am happy to edit this question.

> https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/

Comment: Please note that even if PHPMailer offers that feature (I don't really know) you'll still get a separate copy of the message for each recipient.

Comment: so perhaps I would need to play about with request time, I am assuming so it keeps the http request open until all emails are sent... I am happy to leave a computer on all day if I have to as this is a once in a life time solution for me... and must use phpmailer.

Comment: Sadly, sending e-mail takes the time it takes. You should add pending messages to a queue and have a background process that sends them.

Comment: I could use ajax, to make a request for each of the recipients, and let it run until it's done I suppose unless this is a very bad idea (I can't think of any reasons why it would be) as this is a once of email sending then I don't think it should be a problem...

Comment: IMHO, AJAX would be more difficult to code and would be less robust (if connection drops or browser is closed, deliveries stop at a random point).

Comment: Use the 'sendtoqueue' function to put it in a spool. It will at least be quicker than PHP opening and closing the SMTP socket for every email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do that using only PHPMailer. I had a look at the class methods, nothing linked to such a thing.

Worx International Inc. has another solution called PHPMailer-ML that could provide a good solution to your needs : http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=phpmailerml